# Google App Engine - Updating a blobstore via byte array using simulated POST

Tags: java, google-app-engine, post, blobstore, simulate

I'm getting the following exception when I try to simulate a post request to upload to the app engine blobstore using Java:

> ```
> WARNING: /_ah/login
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>   at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.encodeEmailAsUserId(LoginCookieUtils.java:89)
>   at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LoginCookieUtils.createCookie(LoginCookieUtils.java:41)
>   at com.google.appengine.api.users.dev.LocalLoginServlet.doPost(LocalLoginServlet.java:90)
> ```

Here's is the code that is doing the POST request:

```
byte[] htmlData = // ...I already have the byte array I want to store/update)

    BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();
            String uploadURL = blobstoreService.createUploadUrl("/upload");

                         //add host if in dev mode
             if(uploadURL.indexOf("http") == -1)
             {
                 uploadURL = "http://localhost:8888" + uploadURL;
             }
             URL url = new URL(uploadURL);
             // create a boundary string
             String boundary = MultiPartFormOutputStream.createBoundary();
             URLConnection urlConn = MultiPartFormOutputStream.createConnection(url);
             urlConn.setReadTimeout(15000);
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "*/*");
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", MultiPartFormOutputStream.getContentType(boundary));
             // set some other request headers...
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
             urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
             // no need to connect because getOutputStream() does it
             MultiPartFormOutputStream out = new MultiPartFormOutputStream(urlConn.getOutputStream(), boundary);
out.writeField("param", "value")
out.writeFile("myFile", "multipart/form-data", "content.html", htmlData);
         out.close();
```

Then in upload.java

```
public class Upload extends HttpServlet 
{

    private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException, IOException 
    {
        UserService userService = UserServiceFactory.getUserService();
        User user = userService.getCurrentUser();
        Map<String, BlobKey> blobs = blobstoreService.getUploadedBlobs(req);
        BlobKey blobKey = blobs.get("myFile");
        String value = req.getParameter("param");
        Topic t = pm.getObjectById(Topic.class, key);
        t.setParam("value");
    try
    {
        pm.makePersistent(t);
    }
```

....

Why am I getting an exception for encodeEmailAsUserId?

P.S. The writeFields persist and update just fine in the Datastore, but I still get this exception.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this. The problem is that the example I pulled the MultiPartStream code from did not set the header for the authentication cookie.

I simply added the following to my middle-man servlet that passes the Post data off to the Upload servlet.

```
    Cookie [] cookies = req.getCookies();
    String name = cookies[0].getName();
    String value = cookies[0].getValue();
```

...

```
 urlConn.setRequestProperty("Cookie", name + "=" + value);
```

Comment: Note that in the recent update to SDK it is possible to create blobs programmatically, without procuring such request. You can use Files API for that, as described in http://code.google.com/intl/pl/appengine/docs/java/blobstore/overview.html#Writing_Files_to_the_Blobstore (for Java).